# Check if text is being truncated inside UILabel or not for Read More button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to set the number of lines property to 7 and see if my current text is all visible within the 7 lines or not. if its not then i will show a button below which will set the number of lines to 0 at the press of it. The UIlable exists inside a table cell, auto layout will adjust the size.

How can i check if my text is being truncated in the uilable or not? like if it exceeds the 7 lines or not. (the text can contain any combination of new lines and text, so i cant just count the newlines or number of characters, it will have be approximate, but not equal to 7 lines.)

Comment: Why not set it to 0 in the first place?

Comment: the text can be a lot, so there will have to be a lot of scrolling if the text is a lot... so its more convenient to press read more to expand the text and press the button again (with changed title read less) to contract it back to original size.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have set 2 as numberOfLines, so you can check whether the lines are exceeding:

```
extension UILabel {
    
    func countLabelLines() -> Int {
        // Call self.layoutIfNeeded() if your view is uses auto layout
        let myText = self.text! as NSString
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : self.font]
        
        let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], context: nil)
        return Int(ceil(CGFloat(labelSize.height) / self.font.lineHeight))
    }
    
    func isTruncated() -> Bool {
        guard numberOfLines > 0 else { return false }
        return countLabelLines() > numberOfLines
    }
}
```

usage:

```
if titleLbl.countLabelLines() > 2 {
    print("Truncating")
}
```